# How to get date range partition names on a table between two dates (Given date range)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, partitioning

I am a developer. In my table, I had a date range partitions.
I want to get partition names which are defined for a table between two dates.
I tried with below query and it is returning all the partitions on a table.

```
select * from USER_TAB_PARTITIONS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE NAME' ORDER BY PARTITION_NAME;
```

My requirement is , I will pass two dates as inputs and between those two dates i want to get partition names.
Please suggest query.

Answer (score 1):

That's not very simple; the major obstacle is `user_tab_partitions.high_value` datatype, which is `long`, and it is difficult to work with. Usually you get

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got LONG

error.

However, using a few steps, it can be done. Have a look at this example.

Create a partitioned table and insert a few rows into it:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE test_part
  2  (
  3     datum  DATE,
  4     text   VARCHAR2 (10)
  5  )
  6  PARTITION BY RANGE (datum)
  7     INTERVAL ( NUMTODSINTERVAL (1, 'day') )
  8     (PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE ('01.01.2020', 'dd.mm.yyyy')));

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO test_part
  2     SELECT DATE '2015-08-15', 'Little' FROM DUAL
  3     UNION ALL
  4     SELECT DATE '2020-03-26', 'Foot' FROM DUAL;

2 rows created.
```

What does user_tab_partitions say?

```
SQL> SELECT table_name, partition_name, high_value
  2    FROM user_tab_partitions
  3   WHERE     table_name = 'TEST_PART';

TABLE_NAME      PARTITION_NAME  HIGH_VALUE
--------------- --------------- -----------------------------------
TEST_PART       P0              TO_DATE(' 2020-01-01 00:00:00', 'SY
                                YYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDA
                                R=GREGORIA

TEST_PART       SYS_P63         TO_DATE(' 2020-03-27 00:00:00', 'SY
                                YYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDA
                                R=GREGORIA
```

So, you'd want to extract `date` part from the `high_value` column. The first step is kind of a stupid one - create a new table; basically CTAS:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE temp_utp
  2  AS
  3     SELECT table_name, partition_name, TO_LOB (high_value) high_value
  4       FROM user_tab_partitions;

Table created.
```

For simplicity (in further steps), I'll create a view based on that table which will extract `date` value (line #5):

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_utp
  2  AS
  3     SELECT table_name,
  4            partition_name,
  5            TO_DATE (SUBSTR (high_value, 12, 10), 'rrrr-mm-dd') datum
  6       FROM temp_utp;

View created.
```

The rest is easy now:

```
SQL> SELECT *
  2    FROM v_utp
  3   WHERE datum < DATE '2020-02-15';

TABLE_NAME      PARTITION_NAME  DATUM
--------------- --------------- ----------
TEST_PART       P0              2020-01-01

SQL>
```

---

OK, you'd use two `date` parameters which would then lead to `between` in the final query, but that's easy to modify.

Major drawback here is CTAS which creates `temp_utp` table; you'd have to recreate it as frequently as you add new partitions into the main table. One option is to do it in a scheduled manner, e.g. using a database job (see `dbms_job` and/or `dbms_scheduler` documentation if you don't know how) which would schedule a stored procedure which will then use dynamic SQL, i.e. `execute immediate` to create `temp_utp`. You don't have to recreate a view - it will become valid as soon as a new `temp_utp` table is created.

Comment: Very strange for Oracle, as if `TO_LOB` doesn't work at the beginning. But your solution is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to find solution for the same problem and found that creating a function to convert high value to date works fine like below

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_high_value_date(p_partition_name IN VARCHAR2)
 RETURN DATE
 IS
    l_varchar_date VARCHAR2(4000);
    l_date DATE;
 BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT high_value FROM all_tab_partitions WHERE partition_name = :1 ' INTO l_varchar_date
    USING p_partition_name;
    
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT '||l_varchar_date||' FROM dual' INTO l_date;
    
    RETURN l_date;
 EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'Exc: '||SQLERRM );
    RETURN NULL;
 END;
```

Then you can use this for getting date value

```
SELECT get_high_value_date (partition_name) partition_date, partition_name
  FROM all_tab_partitions
 WHERE table_name = :table
```